# How to create new format on the 2nd datagridview base on the 1st datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

Please see the Screen Shots
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjZrw.jpg)

I want a new format then I will export on excel..
the data in Datagridview1 is the imported excel..
then I want a new format in the datagridview2 as shown in image..

I don't how can I do that..

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question is lacking details. What are you trying to do with the second datagrid? All you say is format. Format for what?

Comment: sorry .. I want to insert the data from dgv1 to dgv2 but in new header ..

Comment: Is it initially imported from excell into a datatable that populates your grid?

Comment: i need to create a middle software to convert the excel file  export from BIOMETRICS to new format of excel, because i need to follow the format in HRIS as shown in dvg2.

Comment: hi codmonger123, yes!

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you are getting data from Excel into .net to change the format and export it back into excel?

Comment: yes sir that was exactly i need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax.

```
For Each drow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    DataGridView2.Rows.Add(drow.Cells(0).Value, drow.Cells(1).Value, drow.Cells(2).Value)
Next
```

*DataGridView2.Rows.Add()* is index based. Putting *drow.Cells(0).Value* at the beginning will add it at the first column and so on and so forth.

*drow.Cells(index).Value*, *index* here is the index of the item you are getting from the column  of your DataGridView1. Pretty straightforward. No much explanation needed I guess.

Comment: Anthems answer is correct to copy the data from datagrid to datagrid but what you should really do is just do it through data tables and lose the datagrids. I am assuming that you are prob. Just changing format and will schedule the job to automatically happen when ever you schedule it in the task scheduler.

Comment: I just simply gave him what he needs I guess. _"I want to insert the data from dgv1 to dgv2 but in new header"_. :)

Comment: You did and I gave you a thumbs up